# How nerve impulses are coded?

Tags: biophysics

Various stimuli from our sense organs travel as electrical signals through nerves to our brain. But how is the information coded in that signal? Is that in the form of magnitude of potential, frequency, etc.?

Comment: Pulse frequency, I believe, but this is more a Biology than a Physics question.

Comment: Pulse rate. It is partly random, but at lower stimulus frequencies it may be correlated with the phase of sound in the ear.